# Build errors after updating to cordova 5.0.0 (CordovaChromeClient, DroidGap, CordovaWebView)

Tags: android, cordova, upgrade, cordova-cli

I'm trying to update Cordova to 5.0.0 in a project originaly build with 2.7.0 (I know it's a long shot).

I started a brand new cordova project and copied my frontend build to `www/` folder. I also copied my custom libs to `platform/android/libs/` and `platform/android/src/`.

When building with **cordova CLI** (`cordova build android`) I receive several errors:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient;
                         ^
error: cannot find symbol
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
                         ^
error: no interface expected here
public class MyWebView extends CordovaWebView
                                        ^
error: cannot find symbol
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient;
                         ^
```

It seems there are no plugin corresponding to those classes and [cordova sources](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/search?q=CordovaChromeClient&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) still refer to it but it's not there.

Since [cordova 3.3.0](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2013/12/16/cordova-330.html) Cordova is used as a Library Project instead of a `.jar`, so `.jar` file is not mandatory.

`Droidgap` [has been deprecated](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5471) for `CordovaActivity`.

What about `CordovaChromeClient` and `CordovaWebView`? Are those deprecated as well?

Answer (score 2):

For the **`CordovaWebView`** the issue is that you are trying to extend, rather than implement it. CordovaWebView is an interface, not a class.

You may want to change your code to something like:

```
public class MyWebView implements CordovaWebView
```

Or you can inherit from `CordovaWebViewImpl`, which is a class that already implements CordovaWebView:

```
public class MyWebView extends CordovaWebViewImpl
```

---

It looks like **`CordovaChromeClient`** was removed in v4.0.0 when they made some changes to their default webview.